# Changing boundary color and increase thickness of a feature in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I'm trying to find elevation using GEE, but I want to set boundary thickness for each country for better representation. How can I do this? Here is the link for code. You can see when two countries Pakistan and Afghanistan showed, boundary thickness is less visible

```js
var pakistan = ee.FeatureCollection("users/Fall2019/PakistanAdministrativeBoundaries"),
    table4 = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");

// Load Pakistan boundary and ICT 
var ICT = pakistan.filter(ee.Filter.eq("adm1_name","Islamabad"));
// Map.addLayer(ICT, {}, "ICT");
// Map.centerObject(ICT, 8); 
var Afghanistan = table4.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co','AF'))

// set styling
var styling = {color: 'blue', fillColor: '00000000'};
var styling2 = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer(pakistan.style(styling))
Map.addLayer(Afghanistan.style(styling2))

var srtm = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4");
var topography = ee.Terrain.products(srtm);
// print("Toopographic products", topography);
Map.addLayer(topography.select(2).clip(pakistan), {min:0, max:359}, 'Pakistan', true);
Map.addLayer(topography.select(2).clip(Afghanistan), {min:0, max:359}, 'Afghanistan', true);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/50aa9ad854f70894da2c94dc026d6a45

Answer (score 3):

To change the line width, you can add `width` to the styling parameters:

```js
var styling = {color: 'blue', fillColor: '00000000', width: 4};
var styling2 = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000', width: 4};
Map.addLayer(pakistan.style(styling));
Map.addLayer(Afghanistan.style(styling2));
```

However, that only visually affects the surrounding border, not the border between the countries; this is because the SRTM90_V4 image is drawn *above* the lines, hiding them. If you want to see all the lines, you can add the boundary layers *after* the image layers, instead of before:

```js
Map.addLayer(topography.select(2).clip(pakistan), {min:0, max:359}, 'Pakistan', true);
Map.addLayer(topography.select(2).clip(Afghanistan), {min:0, max:359}, 'Afghanistan', true);

Map.addLayer(pakistan.style(styling));
Map.addLayer(Afghanistan.style(styling2));
```

That change produces this result, without changing the line width:

[image: Screenshot of revised map]

Comment: Thanks alot for this amazing answer

Comment: can we show names of countries above the map? Because names are just hidden

Comment: or any other way to show names of cities which we used in shapefile?

Comment: @MuhammadSobanBehzad That's a different question, and I don't have the expertise to answer it. Please post it separately, not in comments! Comments get seen by a lot fewer people.

Comment: sure I will post it